# How to edit setup.exe resources

Tags: windows, setup-project

I want to edit .net setup.exe resources.
My requirement is 
1.Remove exe file from Setup.exe
2.Insert new exe file into Setup.exe

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the setup but the easiest is using reshacker or any other petool.
If the setup is encrypted it is a lot harder, you might want to check out RE site's like biwreversing or seekndestroy.